# Adding new fields to Prestashop cart back office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to add fields to the prestashop 1.6 cart back office, i.e. I need something similar to http://nemops.com/prestashop-products-new-tabs-fields/#.VuysZfl97IU

I know that I can easily manipulate the Admin Cart code to get the result I need but I'm wondering if there is a 'correct' way to do it - like in the product tab solution.

A 'correct' way as in:

- encapsulate in a model
- works on any prestashop version that keeps compatible API
- works on any theme